# Aggregate match documents using nested documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a document structure as so:

```
{
   "name": "Bob",
   "configurations": [
      {
         "version": 0,
         "isValid": true,
         "isPublished": false
      },
      {
         "version": 1,
         "isValid": false,
         "isPublished": true
      }
   ]
}
```

I wish to find all such document where there exists a configuration where both `isValid` is true and `isPublished` is true. For such a query, the example I gave above should *not* be returned since the none of the configurations have both of the flags set as true.

I first tried something like:

```
coll.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         "configurations.isValid": true,
         "configurations.isPublished": true
      }
   }
])
```

This isn't what I want because this simply checks if there exists a configuration with `isValid` set to true and if there also exists another configuration with `isPublished` set to true. I tried fixing this via:

```
coll.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         "permissions": {
            "isValid": true,
            "isPublished": true
         }
      }
   }
])
```

but this returns zero results. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Figured it out:

```
coll.aggregate([
   {$match: { configurations: { $elemMatch: { $and: [ {isValid: true}, {isPublished: true}  ] } } }}  
])
```

Answer (score 1):

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TVWzMDfbT-n)

`$elemMatch` will help you to find arrays with condition matches.

```
db.collection.find({
  configurations: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "isValid": true,
      "isPublished": true
    }
  }
})
```

For aggregation, [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MQKS1_gOlMo), Simply use the above in `$match`

Comment: I'm aware of `$elemMatch` but I need to use `aggregate` as the question states. I need aggregate to perform further filters and other operations down the line.

Comment: You can use this in `aggregate`. [Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MQKS1_gOlMo)